# I am needing to end a Do-While loop

Tags: c++

I have a menu that I created. I have all the options that a user can go too to see a certain something, so for them to continue on with the program they have to type end to move on to the next section of code. But my problem is that when they type end, it turns it into an infinite loop. Can anyone here here is the code.

```
    int var = 1;
    int main=1;
    char dd[] = "done";

      do
        {
            cout << "\n\n\nEnter the number of one of the following and I will explain!\n";
            cout << "1.integer  2.boolian   3.floats   4.doubles   5.character";
            cout << "\n\n[when you are done type 'done' to continue]\n\n";
            cin >> option || dd;

            if (option == 1)
            { blah blah blah blah
            }


            else if (option ==2)
            {
             blah blah blah
            }

            else if (dd=="done") //when user types 'done' it goes into infinite loop.
              { break;}

      while (var==1);
```

Comment: What do you think that `cin >> option || dd;` does?

Comment: You can't compare strings like, "dd=="done".

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> option || dd;
```

This code doesn't extract input into both `option` and `dd`. The operator `||` is not something to be used like a "pipe". Rather, you can chain calls to the extractor by using `>>` a second time:

```
cin >> option >> dd;
```

Moreover, you should be using `std::string` for `dd` because comparing C-strings only compares their addresses, not the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the fail bit - See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ after fixing the line `cin >> option || dd;`

Answer (score 0):

You´ll need to compare raw C-Strings (`char*`) with `strcmp()`. To compare if `dd` == "done" use strcmp(dd, "done")==0.

EDIT:

To use `strcmp` you should `#include<cstring>`

EDIT2: As pointed out in other answers and comments, seeing the whole code it will be better to change to `std::string`. But, if you really wants to keep using `char*`, use `strcmp` to compare as stated above.

Comment: Use std::string instead.

Comment: @Ed Heal `std::string` in this case (things that come from streams, etc) is better. I just did not want to break the datatypes the author used.

Comment: @wesley.mesquita _'I just did not want to break the datatypes the author used.'_ That's why I didn't downvote your answer ...